# What kind of insulation is used on commercial aircraft?

Tags: aircraft-design, boeing, fire

How are commercial aircraft insulated and what kind of fire barrier material is being used?  How much insulation is required in a typical Boeing 747 vs. a Boeing 787?

Comment: most of what is on the aircraft is not flammable, you don't want some faulty wire torching the entire aircraft

Comment: @ratchetfreak: [You sure don't.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swissair_Flight_111)

Answer (score 4):

This [article](http://www.boeing.com/commercial/aeromagazine/articles/2011_q4/4/) from Boeing describes fire safety on their planes, and they mention "fire-protective insulation blankets." A quick google search suggests that in non-aviation contexts, these are usually ceramic fiber. So it seems likely that at least one form of fire insulation in modern transport-class aircraft is ceramic fiber fire blankets.

Comment: foil-backed fiberglass is (or at least was) also used, and there are [foam insulation products](http://www.aerospace-technology.com/contractors/thermal/evonik/) that are popular because unlike ceramic/glass fiber insulation they don't kick up irritating fibers when you cut and work them.